# sc is not defined while running executable python code

Tags: pyspark

I am running the following the code in spark submit(Spark 2.3.0) and getting "NameError: name 'sc' is not defined"

```
    from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
    from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit
     from pyspark.sql.types import *

    if __name__  == "__main__":
      sc=SparkContext()

      sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
      forecast = sc.read.load('/user/gg/LV_hadoop_example.csv', 
      format='csv', header='true', inferSchema='true', sep=',')
      forecast = forecast.filter(forecast['Total_scaled_forecast'] > 0)
      forecast.saveAsTextFile("word_count11.txt")
```

Comment: I added sc=SparkContext() to the file, and i am still getting the same error.

Comment: 1) Please fix your indentation- the code you pasted here won't run. 2) [edit] your question to include the full traceback.

Answer (score 2):

In spark 2.3.0, the correct way to load a csv file using:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# initiate spark instance
spark = SparkSession.builder
            .master("local")
            .appName("abc")
            .getOrCreate()

# read csv file
df = spark.read.csv('/user/gg/LV_hadoop_example.csv')
```

Check the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html) for more examples.